# I accidently cancelled the upgrade (20.10), what can I do? what's the risk

Tags: 20.04, do-release-upgrade, 20.10

I was upgrading ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 while upgrading process is going on, I accidentally cancelled the upgrading process. Now after a restart it showing *Ubuntu 20.04 has experienced an internal error*. What should I do?

Comment: I would not login to GUI (assuming you're talking about Ubuntu Desktop; you didn't specify). I would login to a text terminal only, depending on what part of the upgrade was being performed (again you didn't specify; ie. download of packages, or installation.. and at what stage of installation..), I'd possibly `sudo apt update` to check to see what sources were there, assuming it looks good, then `sudo apt full-upgrade` & follow from there, dealing with any problems (eg. it may want `dpkg-reconfigure -a` etc if so I'd do that too).  If you didn't cleanly reboot, I'd `fsck` before any of this

Answer (score 3):

Aborting a release-upgrade is among the worst things you can do to your system. During a release-upgrade, your system is highly vulnerable to damage or corruption.

It's possible that you now have an incompatible mix of different-version packages that causes your frankensystem to crash unexpectedly ("internal error"). It might be fixable...or it might not.

- Check your sources: Make sure you have only 20.10 sources. No older sources, no PPAs, and no non-Ubuntu sources.
- Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`. Fix all errors. Your package system must be clean. If instructed to run `sudo apt install --fix-missing`, do so...but it's a bad sign.
- Run `sudo dpkg configure --all`. Fix all errors.
- Run `sudo apt autoremove` only after your package system is clean and error-free.
- Run `sudo snap refresh`
- **WARNING**: These are not magical incantations, and this is not a guaranteed recipe for success. You are expected to understand each command (and it's consequences) before you run it.

It might work. It might not. If you have the time and skills, it might be worth trying. If you don't know how to check your sources or how to read apt error output, then it's time to back up your data and reinstall.

If you run into an unfixable error, then backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: I tried the commands ```sudo apt update``` and ```sudo apt dist-upgrade``` and it ran well. It didn't show to install fix missing packages. Is it a good sign